# Denied entry to eastern european country - Implications for Singapore immigration

Tags: singapore, denial-of-entry

I was denied entry into an Eastern European country (non-EU). The official reason that was given to me was "others". I have researched this particular country's immigration practices since the incident and am reasonably sure it was racial profiling.

Now, I was wondering about the implications of it on entering Singapore to work. The Singapore immigration form asks if I have ever been denied entry to any country.

Do I think immigration departments share the info to the point where SG has any idea? Not a chance, especially since the denial was spurious. I have spoken to former immigration officers of the UK about this who have said it seems obviously spurious and that most immigration departments do not share data.

Would I prefer to be honest? Yes.

Now, to the question. Most of the info I can find on this is regarding past denials to Singapore and people wanting to know if they can return to Singapore. I have seen no case similar to mine whereby I have been denied entry to a different country. Should I mention it? Should I seek additional clearance from ICA before flying? Will it make it more likely to be denied entry to SG on an IPA letter? Would much appreciate advice from immigration professionals especially SG related.

Comment: I wrote an answer to this question when you posted it but then didn't finish because I realized I don't know much about the immigration procedure you will be using for Singapore.  Is there no visa?  What documents will you need to show the airline when you board the flight?  Can you link to a web page describing the process?  (My answer is basically that you should ask a lawyer; in theory your prior refusal was benign and Singapore should admit you after you explain what happened, but I don't know for sure: Singaporean officers might have a very low threshold for "red flags.")